# Scripts on non-standard ports

Tags: apache

How do you install scripts on non-standard ports (ports other than the default 80)

Like how cPanel uses port 2082

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Apache `Listen` or `VHost` directives to cause Apache to bind to additional ports.